# Hiding DataGridView rows while preserving index

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView used for displaying the data for a custom class, foo.

```
public class foo
{
    public string header{get;set;}
    public int value{get;set;}
    public bool isHidden{get;set;}
}
```

Foo gets read from the database and gets processed from a JSON string and then inserted into the DataGridView for display to the user.

```
List<foo> listOfFoo = new List<foo>();
DataTable fooTable = new DataTable();
myDataGridView.DataSource = fooTable;

private void getFoo()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string getData = myWebClient.DownloadString(/*url of server*/);

    Dictionary<string,object> fooArg = (Dictionary<string,object>)js.DeserializeObject(getData);
    object[] foo = (object[])fooArg["foo"];
    for(int i = 0; i < foo.Length; i++)
    {
        Dictionary<string,object> fooStep = (Dictionary<string,object>)foo[i];
        foo temp = new foo();

        temp.header = (string)fooStep["header"];
        temp.value = (int)fooStep["value"];
        temp.isHidden = (bool)fooStep["isHidden"];
        listOfFoo.Add(temp);
    }
    drawFoo();
}
private void drawFoo()
{
    fooTable.Rows.Clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < listOfFoo.Count; i++)
    {
        //myDataGridView has two columns, header and value. isHidden is not shown in the table itself
        foo i = listOfFoo.ElementAt(i);
        fooTable.Rows.Add(i.header, i.value);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm using the index of the row to preserve the order of the foos (DataGridView is not sortable). If I modified my drawFoo function to the below, will the indexing be preserved? I have an insert function that inserts a new foo into the list below the one currently selected in the DataGridView. Would it mess up the indexing, considering when I post the listOfFoo back to the server it has to be in the appropriate order. Is there a better way to handle this? I'm open for suggestions. Thanks, people smarter than I am!

```
private void drawFoo()
{
    fooTable.Rows.Clear();
    for(int q = 0; q < listOfFoo.Count; q++)
    {
        //myDataGridView has two columns, header and value. isHidden is not shown in the table itself
        foo i = listOfFoo.ElementAt(q);
        fooTable.Rows.Add(i.header, i.value);
        if(i.isHidden)
            myDataGridView.Rows[q].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding rows in the middle or front will change akk indexes after. Hiding doesn't. Now which is it? Do you know what the correct index of the new rows is?

Comment: A better way would be to have unique ID's on your records, and use that ID to perform database level actions (insert / update / delete).  This you, you guarantee that you're interacting with the appropriate record.

Comment: @TaW Hiding preserves the index, correct. So if I inserted a foo before the hidden one, it would shift the hidden foo down, would it not? For example, if [0,1,2,3,4,5] is my list, and 3 is hidden. if I added a foo between 2 and 3 called 7, would it look like [0,1,2,7,3,4,5]?

Comment: No. It always looks: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.. If you need to keep the original order you need to either put the original index in a separate column or in the tag of a column or the row itself : `row.Tag = row.Index;`.